# SQL - Updating table from other table selecting update row based on "priority" setting. (PostgreSQL 11.0)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update the 'ea' column from A with the value of 'ea' in table B.

Table A has 'cfn' and 'ea' and has unique product entries.

Table B has 'cfn' and 'ea' and 'dchain' and may have multiple entries for the same product (different dchain).

Table B 'dchain' field is linked to Table C which has 'dc' and a 'prio' setting (integer).

The record to select from table B to update table A needs to be based on the priority of table C.
I have tried multiple options with limit and order but somehow I'm missing the right sequence as the result is always wrong.....

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image: Table C]

Comment: Please add your tired code

Comment: this was the code I had previously:
update cfn_check a set a.ea = b.ea
from mstrdata_s153 b where b.dchain='DR' and a.cfn = b.cfn;
Issue now is that I need to change select of b.dchain to the highest value of the added table C

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can get the values to update using:

```
select distinct on (b.cfn) b.*
from b join
     c
     on b.dchain = c.dc
order by b.cfn, c.priority;
```

Note:  This assumes that lower priorities are more important.  If higher priorities are add `desc` to the second key.

Then you can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update a
    set a.ea = bc.ea
    from (select distinct on (b.cfn) b.*
          from b join
               c
               on b.dchain = c.dc
          order by b.cfn, c.priority
         ) bc
    where bc.cfn = a.cfn;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks !

Perfect solution and I learned a lot !